# C# how to populate variable with same RegEx results?

Tags: c#

I'm having bit of struggle with selecting some data from given dataset. Let's say I do have a list of cars without specified types. So I need to select them by names and from those I'm able to know types.

```
var ItemList = Entries?.Where(entry => (entry?.Type?.IsCar() ?? false))
    ?.OrderBy(entry => entry?.Name?.RegexMatchSuccessIgnoreCase(@"ferrari|lamborghini|mclaren"))        //sports cars
    ?.OrderBy(entry => entry?.Name?.RegexMatchSuccessIgnoreCase(@"bmw|audi|mercedes"))                  // personal cars
    ?.OrderBy(entry => entry?.Name?.RegexMatchSuccessIgnoreCase(@"man|iveco"))                          //trucks
    ?.ThenBy(entry => entry?.Weight ?? int.MaxValue)
    ?.ToArray();
```

This will get me list of all cars and ordered by names and weight which is kind of ok, but not fully.

What I'm looking for is to be able to fill `ItemList` by each type, and if there is no car from that type, fill it with another type. So firstly `ItemList` have to contain only sports cars, if there are none, try to find out personal cars, if there are none, try to find out trucks.

Eg. something like:

```
var ItemList = Entries?.Select(entry =>
    entry?.Name?.RegexMatchSuccessIgnoreCase(@"ferrari|lamborghini|mclaren") ??       //sports cars
    entry?.Name?.RegexMatchSuccessIgnoreCase(@"bmw|audi|mercedes") ??        // personal cars
    entry?.Name?.RegexMatchSuccessIgnoreCase(@"man|iveco")                 //trucks
    ).DefaultIfEmpty(false);
```

But this gives me true/false since first one returns entry with which I can work.

> Can somebody kick my brain how to select those by type and be able to use them as entries not bools?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated comment: In a few days, that code will be unreadable even for you. Rather than doing everything in a "single" statement, I'd suggest on improving readability, which will at the same time help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to write the classes ourselves and populate with data.

Comment: Above comments are right. You could make a static class to perform these operations for you such as bool EntryNameMatchesRegex("_regex_") or List<Entries> SelectEntriesWithMatchingResults("_regex_") and call each one distinctly. Look up some principles of single responsibility

Comment: Do not use Regex.  The values are in a DataTable and it is much easier to group and sort rows of a datatable than to use regex.

Comment: You may or may not have a list of something for which the items may or may not be null, which may or may not have a type, name, or weight. You are using regex when don't need it, and you are checking for null on the results from linq extension methods when they never do.. This really is a case of start again, and potentially make a more solid class and methods to hold your concerns

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question of how to "to be able to fill ItemList by each type, and if there is no car from that type, fill it with another type" by using the conditional operator. As you did not give an *MCVE* as pointed out in the comments I will be using a simple list of strings as my example (you should be able to draw it to the context of your example by simple substitution i.e. instead of checking for each single value you would check for each Regex match)

```
var entries = new List<string>(){"a", "a", "b"};

var itemList = entries.Any(e => e == "a") ? entries.Where(e => e == "a") 
                      : entries.Any(e => e == "b")  
                      ? entries.Where(e => e == "b") // continue for all your types
                      : null;
```

The idea is quite simply check if the list contains any matching of your specific type if so return all elements of that type and short circuit else check for the next type and so on. You can probably do this more efficient this was just to give a possible solution to your problem